# Extra lines present in 3d graph using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to create a 3d graph plotting the planets' orbits, the code works fine for 2d projection, however 3d encounters some extra lines (brown line). I can't find the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Mass = [332837, 0.055, 0.85, 1.000, 0.107, 317.85, 95.159, 14.500, 17.204, 0.003]
a = ["", 0.387, 0.723, 1.000, 1.523, 5.202, 9.576, 19.293, 30.246, 39.509]
e = ["", 0.21, 0.01, 0.02, 0.09, 0.05, 0.06, 0.05, 0.01, 0.25]
beta = ["", 7.00, 3.39, 0.00, 1.85, 1.31, 2.49, 0.77, 1.77, 17.5]

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)


def get_planet_data(index, projection="2d"):

    r = (a[index] * (1 - e[index]**2))/ (1 - e[index] * np.cos(theta))
    x = r*np.cos(theta)
    y = r*np.sin(theta)
    if projection == "3d":
        angle = beta[index] * np.pi / 180
        xx = x*np.cos(angle)
        yy = y
        zz = x*np.sin(angle)
        return xx, yy, zz
    return x, y


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(-40, 40)
ax.set_ylim(-40, 40)
ax.set_zlim(-40, 40)
xList = []
yList = []
zList = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    data = get_planet_data(i, "3d")
    xList.append(data[0])
    yList.append(data[1])
    zList.append(data[2])

# ax.plot(xList[0], yList[0], zList[0],
#         xList[1], yList[1], zList[1],
#         xList[2], yList[2], zList[2],
#         xList[3], yList[3], zList[3])
ax.plot(xList[4], yList[4], zList[4],
        xList[5], yList[5], zList[5],
        xList[6], yList[6], zList[6],
        xList[7], yList[7], zList[7],
        xList[8], yList[8], zList[8])

plt.show()
```

I found out matplotlib is not as good with 3d graphing as 2d, and was trying to use pyqtgraph or mayavi as alternatives.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a ton of experience with the 3D plotting API. But it looks like it has something to do with plotting all the lines in a single plot call. Try breaking it out into a `for` loop instead.

(I also made more use of numpy to get rid of the other loops.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

a = np.array([0.387, 0.723, 1.000, 1.523, 5.202, 9.576, 19.293, 30.246, 39.509])
e = np.array([0.21, 0.01, 0.02, 0.09, 0.05, 0.06, 0.05, 0.01, 0.25])
beta = np.array([7.00, 3.39, 0.00, 1.85, 1.31, 2.49, 0.77, 1.77, 17.5])

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)


def get_planet_data(index, projection="2d"):
    r = (a[index] * (1 - e[index]**2))/ (1 - e[index] * np.cos(theta))
    x = r*np.cos(theta)
    y = r*np.sin(theta)
    if projection == "3d":
        angle = beta[index]*np.pi/180
        xx = x*np.cos(angle)
        yy = y
        zz = x*np.sin(angle)
        return xx, yy, zz
    return x, y


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.set_xlim(-40, 40)
ax.set_ylim(-40, 40)
ax.set_zlim(-40, 40)

xx, yy, zz = get_planet_data(np.arange(9)[:,None], "3d")
for i in range(4, 9):
    ax.plot(xx[i], yy[i], zz[i],)

plt.show()
```

[image]